# git push can not find -o option

Tags: git

I have run `git push -o merge_request.create origin mybranch` but get "error unknown switch 'o'", see screenshot below.

Git version: 2.9.5

I've checked the doc that versions are newer than 2.1.0 should support -o options.

Does anybody know what goes wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Please do not share images of code and/or errors. Instead, copy and paste them here. You should do this since it is impossible to debug screenshots.

Answer (score 3):

The current version of git is `2.36.1`. Your version is quite old. I'm not sure what doc you were looking at, but the `--help` output clearly does not show the `-o` option. Looking at the source, it doesn't look like this option was available until `2.10.0`.

The feature was added to `builtin/push.c` in commit `f6a4e61fbb6`, and `git tag --contain f6a4e61fbb6` doesn't show anything earlier than `2.10.0`:

```
$ git log -G push-option --oneline builtin/push.c
d8052750c5 builtin/push.c: add push.pushOption config
f6a4e61fbb push: accept push options
$ git tag --contain f6a4e61fbb
v2.10.0
v2.10.0-rc0
v2.10.0-rc1
v2.10.0-rc2
v2.10.1
v2.10.2
...
```

Comment: Great answer. Docs for latest 2.36.1 (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push ) and 2.10.5 (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push/2.10.5)